# Node.js : get css file with html render

Tags: node.js

How can I include a CSS file in my HTML file with a HTML render in Node.js?

Here's what I do:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./general.css" />
```

And then is the error when I'm going to localhost:8333/general.css:

```
Cannot GET /general.css
```

My module renderer script is the following:

```
app.set('views', __dirname);
app.engine('html', engines.mustache);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

How should I do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can to use Express' static middleware to serve static files like (client-side) JS and CSS:

```
app.use(express.static());
```

That will, by default, try and find static files in `./public` (relative to the script you configure the middleware from):

```
yourproject/app.js   <-- if configured here
yourproject/public/  <-- it will look here
```

If you use this in your HTML/template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/general.css" />
```

The middleware will find and (if found) serve `./public/css/general.css`.

If you want a setup where your CSS files are in the same directory as your application script, you can tell the middleware where to look for files by passing a directory as first argument:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```